# Android-Maps-Extensions Generating Error with MapFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-extensions

I am converting my existing Google Map code (most of which, was generated when I selected "Google Maps Activity" in Android Studio) to the Android-Maps-Extensions library in order to use both a Marker Clustering which is part of this library and an Overlapping Marker Spiderfier tool developed with Android-Map-Extensions.

Right now, I have a problem with this method (I made it smaller than my actual existing method to make it easier to read so if there's any mistakes, please let me know and I will edit it):

```
private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap(); //ERROR IS HERE
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }
```

Basically the line:

```
mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

is generating a message that says

```
Incompatible Types:
 Required: com.androidmapsextensions.GoogleMap
 Found: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
```

Here are my import statements (I included all of them just in case, including the ones currently commented out):

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.androidmapsextensions.*;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
//import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
```

I changed android:name from "android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" to "com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment" in activity_maps.xml to look like this:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:id="@+id/map" tools:context=".MapsActivity"
    android:name="com.androidmapsextensions.SupportMapFragment" />
```

Also, these are the dependencies in my Gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.0.0'
}
```

Still getting the same error message though. Was there something I forgot to change or something I need to add?

If you want to know more information, please leave a comment below and I will respond or edit this post.

Comment: How is mMap defined?

Comment: @TimCastelijns "private GoogleMap mMap;" and it's declared outside the method.

Comment: Make sure that that definition of GoogleMap refers to the right package

Comment: @TimCastelijns When I right click on "GoogleMap", click "Go to", and then "Declaration", it takes me to "package com.androidmapsextensions;" so it looks like it is referring to the right package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to use `getExtendedMap` instead of `getMap` (or `getExtendedMapAsync`) as described in [Migration from Android API v2](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-maps-extensions/wiki#migration-from-android-api-v2).

Note that de-clustering or Overlapping Marker Spiderfier like you call it in demo application is not production ready and you will have to adjust it, so it doesn't crash.

Full disclosure: I'm Android Maps Extensions developer.

Comment: getMap is deprecated now